# Calculate seconds (or milliseconds) between two locations

Tags: objective-c, math, time, location

Currently my function goes like this:

```
#define kKILOMETER                              1000
#define kSeconds_To_Milliseconds    1000
#define kHOUR 60
#define kMINUTE 60
#define kLongDistance_3KM   3

- (long)calculateTimeToMilliSecondsWithDistance:(double)distance andSpeed:(float)theSpeed
{
    // Distance arrive in meters
    double kmDistance = distance/kKILOMETER;

    long time =
    (long)(((kmDistance - kLongDistance_3KM)/[self.ref integerForKey:@"MAX_SPEED"])*kHOUR*kMINUTE*kSeconds_To_Milliseconds);

    NSLog(@"calculateTimeToMilliSeconds -> sleep to (sec): %li, maxSpeed: %li",
          time/1000, (long)[self.ref integerForKey:@"MAX_SPEED"]);

    [self startSendSleepTime:time];
    return time;
}
```

My "MAX_SPEED" value refer to 200 km/h.
What I get back is wrong value.
What I want to to calculate the time using my distance minus 3 kilometers with speed of 200 km/h but somehow it mess up.
Also it would be even better to get it in seconds, for that I should remove the `kSeconds_To_Milliseconds`, right?

I don't know what mess up for me.

**EDIT 1:**

For example:

```
2014-03-19 18:12:39.624 Cellular Radar[3338:60b] Distance to car: 4713, Trap Radius: 900
2014-03-19 18:12:39.673 Cellular Radar[3338:60b] calculateTimeToMilliSeconds -> sleep to (sec): 2055, maxSpeed: 3
2014-03-19 18:12:39.684 Cellular Radar[3338:60b] Sleep for (2055.000000 seconds | 34.250000 minutes | 0.570833 hours)
```

Comment: can you post what you expect and what you actually get ?

Comment: The results seems to be fine given the input distance = 4713. Did you notice that max speed is 3 ? (you said it was 200 in your question)

Comment: You right, that means if the distance is 4713-3000(1713) and the speed is 200 so the time will be 1713/200=8.565, right?

Comment: yes. about the units (i.e. sec/min/hrs) it all depends on how you treat the values. As long as you remain consistent your results should be correct units-wise